# jQuery GET request works in localhost, but not in production

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I have a request to my own server that works in localhost that is as follows:

```
$.get("/api/quotes", function (data, status){...});
```

which is sent to my server in express which uses `app.use('/api/quotes', quoteRouter)` with the appropriate router/callbacks associated. this request works fine and renders data as expected.

However, upon doing the same request in production, the request gives me an error of

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ().

I am not sure why it does not work in production, but works in local. I have enabled `https` so that the production version matches with `https://localhost:...` through `https.createServer({key:...,cert:...},app).listen(...)` in express.

I am also using `app.use(cors())` on the server side as well.

I have checked that to make sure I am using the right environmental variables (`production`).

Would appreciate any insight. Thank you.

Comment: `404` means the URL is incorrect. You probably installed it in a different directory in production.

Comment: what do you mean "in a different directory"? I have tested a production build on localhost and all works fine. i substituted the same `.env` values on my hosting platform but i still get a 404. none of the files have moved. if `localhost:3001/api/quotes` works, then `website.com/api/quotes` should work as well i think?

Comment: It's not in `/api`, maybe the URL should be `/something/api/quotes`

Comment: ah, i see what you mean. i have checked all my routes (i only have 4) and the root is `/`, with the other being `/api/quotes`. not sure how that could change given im also calling `/api/routes` on the get request client-side and how another directory would be introduced.

Comment: So all the other /api/XXX routes work except this one? Very strange.

Comment: Are there any server logs you can check?

Comment: my error is `{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-02-e1qh1.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-02-e1qh1.mongodb.net:27017 closed]`. i am running the server but this part does not work (am hosting on netlify). not sure what it means but i have to google more i guess.